# How to delete Ingress rules with java synchronously

Tags: java, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, fabric8

I am using Kubernetes and Ingress via fabric8 kubeclient.
I have namespaces with user content and in each namespace i have an ingress rule.

I need to remove the namespaces with user content on request.
But deleting a namespace is not a quick operation.
I want to first delete the ingress rule - so that there is no access to the content - and then asynchronously delete the namespace itself.
Question: is there any way to delete ingress rule synchronously?

All of that code do it async:

```
client.extensions().ingresses().inNamespace(namespaceName).delete();

//or
//client.extensions().ingresses().inNamespace(namespaceName).withName(ingressName).delete();;

client.namespaces().withName(namespaceName).delete();
```

My Ingress config file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    my-cluster: dev-cluster
  name: name_1
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: {{host}}
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: service_1
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

How to delete kubernetes namespace or ingress rule in namespace synchronically?

Comment: I think you should be able to do it with `patch` operation. Could you please share an example of your provided and expected output?

Comment: @RohanKumar Now we are resolving this problem changing domain name with this command:
`client.load(is).inNamespace(namespaceName).createOrReplace();`

Do I understand correctly that you suggested me to solve my problem like this?:
`client.network().v1().ingresses().inNamespace("default").withName("ingress-wildcard-host").patch(PatchContext.of(PatchType.JSON), "[{\"op\": \"remove\", \"path\":\"/spec/rules/0/http/paths/0\"}]");`
Is this better than our solution? Is patch operation synchronized?